# Book with a really tall tower

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this probably about 12 years ago. It was a fantasy book, may have been medieval. I believe the hero has to find a sword to defeat some great evil. The hero was probably young-ish, I suspect it's a young adult book.

Here's the specific bit, there's a scene I remember distinctly. Our hero is climbing this impossibly tall tower to face the big bad. And it went something like "Then I was climbing the stairs. Climbing, climbing. I climbed for so long I became the god of climbing stairs. I knew nothing but climbing." He then faces the big bad and wins with but a single cut to his hand. Of course, when the big bad is defeated the tower collapses. It then was something like "Then I was falling down. I fell for so long I became the god of falling. I watched the cut on my hand heal into a scar, and then I watched the scar fade. I knew nothing but falling." Pretty sure he reaches the ground eventually and survives.

I'm sure those quotes aren't exactly correct but the "god of climbing" and "god of falling" bits stuck out to me when I read it. Unfortunately they are not particularly useful search terms.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate. That doesn't mean that it's a bad question, merely one we've answered before. You will still get points for upvotes, and people can comment on the question and answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *[The Hero and the Crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hero_and_the_Crown)* by Robin McKiney.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77366.The_Hero_and_the_Crown):

> Aerin could not remember a time when she had not known the story; she had grown up knowing it.
>
> It was the story of her mother, the witchwoman who enspelled the king into marrying her, to get an heir that would rule Damar; and it was told that she turned her face to the wall and died of despair when she found she had borne a daughter instead of a son.
> Aerin was that daughter.
>
> But there was more of the story yet to be told; Aerin's destiny was greater than even she had dreamed--for she was to be the true hero who would wield the power of the Blue Sword...

Here's one of the relevant quotes:

> The sound of the mountain tower falling was so loud she could no longer make room for her thoughts, and so she gave up thinking; and blackness hurtled past her, and heavy fragments of that blackness fell with her but did not touch her, and she wondered if she might fall forever, as she had climbed, and thus perhaps become the God That Falls, or perhaps the God That Climbs and Falls.
> <sub>*The Hero and the Crown*, [page 190](https://archive.org/details/herocrown0000mcki_g2q8/page/190/mode/2up?q=%22falling%22)</sub>

Shortly beforehand is the scene where she's cut while defeating the villain:

> Aerin staggered to her feet, and found that she was clutching Gonturan with both hands; and that the palm of one was wet with her own blood where she had seized unwarily at Gonturan’s edge; [...]

---

Identified by doing a Google search for `"god of climbing" "god of falling"`, which turned up [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/12wpxxo/midlate_80s_or_earlier_fantasy_novel_ya_female/) asking to identify the same book, with an answer of *The Hero and the Crown*. I then looked up an online version of the text to find a specific matching quote to verify that it was indeed the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn I googled the same thing, but it must have been different, because I just kept getting bible related links.